# Spring batch not picking task executor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multithreading, spring-batch

This is my spring batch config:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private CRMTService crmtService;

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor myTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Batch-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<String, String>chunk(10)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .processor(itemProcessor())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .taskExecutor(myTaskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<String> itemReader() {
        List<String> list = crmtService.getVertrags();
        return new IteratorItemReader<>(list != null ? list.iterator() : Collections.emptyIterator());
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<String, String> itemProcessor() {
        return item -> {
               //Logic -> This calls a method in service class. In that method I am calling an API for each string and saving the response to mongodb.
        return item;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<String> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            //If we plan to log do anything in future
        };
    }

}
```

Jdk version 11

Spring boot version 2.6.3

I am triggering this spring batch in my service class.

When I am not using task executor, I am able to get all the products (214) in my mongodb [With single thread I am able to get all products but obviously it takes time]. When I am using with task executor I miss 1 or 2 products (212/213).

Also, some 2 interesting observations:

When the spring batch is triggered, These are the logs I get in console:

```
WARN [] 9758 --- [onPool-worker-1] o.s.b.c.c.a.DefaultBatchConfigurer       : No datasource was provided...using a Map based JobRepository 
WARN [] 9758 --- [onPool-worker-1] o.s.b.c.c.a.DefaultBatchConfigurer       : No transaction manager was provided, using a ResourcelessTransactionManager 
INFO [] 9758 --- [onPool-worker-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : **No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor**.
```

Even though I have set task executor in step bean. I am getting this message.

When the spring batch actually starts, the threads which are running are from myTaskExecutor" because in the console I can see the thread's name is starting with "Batch" and this is the prefix I added in spring batch config class.

```
[        Batch-1] c.t.openapi.crmt.conf.SpringBatchConfig  : Processing 123 
[        Batch-3] c.t.openapi.crmt.conf.SpringBatchConfig  : Processing 456
[        Batch-2] c.t.openapi.crmt.conf.SpringBatchConfig  : Processing 789
```

Question 1: Why am I getting no task executor found even when I have defined it explicitly?

Question 2: If it is not picked then why are threads in spring batch are starting with "Batch-"

Even if I use this instead of task executor:

```java
@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<VertragsListe, VertragsListe>chunk(10)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .processor(itemProcessor())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
            .build();
}
```

I still get "No task executor found".

Comment: The warning is about the `JobLauncher` **not** your `Job`. Those are different things. It is used for your step not for the launcher those are totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the WriterExecutor, try debugging the API using the context  processor, has worked for me